# Using XML python library to acces data

Tags: python, xml, algorithm, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a XML string as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n<data serial="1234">\n    <ts>1418823725</ts>\n <r t="P" n="AA"><v>1596787</v><i>62</i></r>\n <r t="P" n="BB"><v>246995</v><i>63</i></r>\n <r t="P" n="CC"><v>0</v><i>0</i></r>\n</data>\n
```

I am trying to parse the string to get the  this using xml library in python as follows:

```
for child in root.iter('r'):
    print child.attrib.get('t')
    print child.attrib.get('n')
    print child.text
```

output shows as:

```
P
AA
None
P
BB
None
P
CC
None
```

How can I access time stamp value `<ts>`, the number `62` `63` and `0` for `AA` `BB` and `CC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findtext()` would be handy here:

```
print root.findtext('ts')
print "----"

for child in root.iter('r'):
        print child.attrib.get('t'), child.attrib.get('n'), child.findtext('i')
```

Prints:

```
1418823725
----
P AA 62
P BB 63
P CC 0
```